# Keeping sustained responsivness

Tags: google-bigquery

Are there any method to obtaining reliable throughput with BigQuery? I've been using it since May or March and we have always seen wild swings in latencies, generally not lasting longer than a few days - however now we are constantly slow.

It seems that this is due to the shared resource pool style of the service, however they do not make it easy to purchase private resources.

How does one obtain consistent, reliable results from BigQuery?

Details of my usage:

- Streaming inserts (1000/s)
- Queries on the streaming dataset(Up to 250GB table size)
- Querying Via. the API using the PHP library

My queries times vary from 2 seconds to 10 minutes. Ideally A query should never exceed the 15 - 30 seconds range. Any information on what might improve my response times would be helpful

Comment: If you can provide some example project id + job ids, we can probably take a look to understand some of the sources of slowness. That said, querying streaming tables will incur some latency overhead, as we're serving the data from a less optimized data source. This overhead shouldn't be on the order of minutes though.

Comment: Well the issue at hand is more or less been chalked up to "a problem engineering is working on" (via. a support case) - however I was hoping to see if anyone else has discovered anything that works for them - an example however would be:
job_pdA7Lk-cjhQOtD6bc7vFUr5K8yE

Comment: Ah. Apologies! I didn't realize you had an existing support case. Poking around a bit, I do see we have some investigations going on, but I'm not familiar with the details. Hopefully they'll get back to you with a reasonable solution.